# Mask ampersand symbol in parameter string of url

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a possibility to encode and decode in xslt 1.0 (firefox) a parameter string of an url, so that the ampersand symbol (&) is not interpreted as a separator of parameters?

Comment: If this is really an XSLT question, please show an XML input sample, your XSLT stylesheet and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the combination `%26` represents the ampersand symbol. More info can be found in this wikipedia article  [- percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about URL encoding an ampersand or XML encoding it?  URL encoded would be `%26`, XML encoded would be `&amp;`.  In one case, the HTTP server would interpret it as "plain text", in the other the XML engine would interpret it as "plain text".

So if I had this XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  /file.cgi?blah%26blah
</xsl:template>
```

I could get that literal output (`/file.cgi?blah%26blah`), and a web server would not interpret it as having two parameters but one (with one parameter ultimately being rendered as `blah&blah`).

But if I have this XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  /file.cgi?blah&amp;blah
</xsl:template>
```

I'll get the output `/file.cgi?blah&blah` and a web server would interpret that as having two parameters.

One last possibility is that you're trying to use XSLT in the browser to manipulate the URL.  In that case, just pass the entire `window.location.href` as a parameter to your XSLT.